# How do i stop the cmd window appearing on my desktop as i have made a delay startup batch file?

Tags: batch-file, invisible, minimized

This is my .bat. All is working fine, except i see the black window on my screen while the countdown is taking place...

```
@echo off
timeout /nobreak /t 8 > nul
start /d "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Skype\" Skype.lnk
exit
```

Ps: `/min` doesn't work, skype doesn't start minimized even if i right click on the `skype.lnk` in the program files and set there start as minimized.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work.  It's a batch + JScript + batch again hybrid script.  Save this with a `.bat` extension and let me know whether it works for you.  If not, I'll do some testing.

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*

:: batch portion

@echo off
tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq cscript.exe" | find /i "cscript.exe" >NUL || (
    start "" cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0"
    exit
)
:: ping -n seconds + 1 (because first ping result is instant)
ping -n 9 localhost > nul
start /d "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Skype\" Skype.lnk
exit

:: JScript portion */
var sh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
sh.Run(WSH.ScriptFullName, 0);
WSH.Sleep(100);
```

I'll attempt to describe the workflow of the script.

1. **cmd batch:** User launches batch script either by double-clicking or entering `batfile.bat` at the `cmd` prompt.
2. Script checks to see whether `cscript.exe` is in the task list.  It isn't.
3. Script re-launches itself using the JScript interpreter instead of the cmd batch interpreter.  Current cmd interpretation exits.
4. **JScript:** The WScript.Shell object [Run method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) re-launches the batch script with the cmd interpreter in a hidden, non-blocking process.
5. After a 100ms pause, JScript reaches the end of the file and exits.  This should be the last of the visible windows.
6. **invisible cmd batch:** Script checks to see whether `cscript.exe` is in the task list.  JScript is still pausing at this point, so `cscript.exe` does exist.
7. Go ping yourself... for 8 seconds.
8. Activate the Skype shortcut in a non-blocking process.
9. Batch script exit.